# text to speech engine in Hindi for android

Tags: android, text-to-speech

i have been trying to implement text to speech feature in my app....it works fine with some 8 basic languages like English, french, German ...but didn't how to get other languages like Hindi.
      I want to implement text to speech feature in Hindi language. I couldn't find any engines for Hindi text to speech

Answer (score 1):

Here is an Text To Speech Engine which supports Hindi

http://www.blissit.org/

The eSpeak TTS engine has support for Hindi, but the quality is not very good.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.googlecode.eyesfree.espeak

Comment: thank u...can't we get free engines..we have to pay to get this engine